# Activate PHP for Apache without using an editor (Unix command line)

Tags: macos, apache, unix, command-line

I know enabling PHP is as easy as uncommenting

`LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

but is there any way of doing this in a single unix command?

Like: find `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` and remove the `#` before it IF  there is a comment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed -i -r 's@^# *(LoadModule php5_module.*)@\1@' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Comment: this returns me the following error: `sed: 1: "s@^# *(LoadModule php5_ ...": \1 not defined in the RE`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed it:

```
sudo sed -i '' 's/#LoadModule php5_module/LoadModule php5_module/g' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```